# Selenium Web Driver not waiting before the full page loads

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate youtube to mp3 conversion using python3 and selenium web driver. The code used is as follows:-

```
from selenium import webdriver

print("Automated Youtube to MP3 downloader")
artist = input("Enter Artist Name: ")
song = input("Enter Song Name: ")
choice = input("Play or Download: ")
choice = choice.lower()

if choice=='download':
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.implicitly_wait(25)

   driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')

   #Selecting ID box
   idBox = driver.find_element_by_class_name('style-scope ytd-searchbox')
   idBox.send_keys(artist+'-'+song)
   searchClick = driver.find_element_by_id('search-icon-legacy')
   searchClick.click()

   queryString = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'video-title')]")
   href = queryString.get_attribute('href')

   driver.get('https://ytmp3.cc/en13/')
   linkHolder = driver.find_element_by_id('input')
   linkHolder.send_keys(href)
   convert = driver.find_element_by_id('submit')
   convert.click()

   buttonGroup = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href^='https://']")
   buttonGroup[0].click()
else:
   print('To code for play option')
```

The problem with this code is that it takes the link of first video on youtube home page and not the desired search query. Could you please suggest a workaround? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you can implement 'wait - untell'  in selenium,

first, add this import in the top of your script

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

then add this code, replace ID_Here by the ID element, or you cannot do that because the request page didn't have a unique element, you can just do time.sleep()
but I think that you can locate the song name for exemple

```
searchClick.click()
wait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ID_Here')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create and use method to all elements loaded completly in webpage

```
 public static void waitForPageLoaded() {

    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
                }
            };
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
        wait.until(expectation);
    } catch (Throwable error) {
        Assert.fail("Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete.");
    }
 
}
```